# Cannot save Checkbox meta box value from a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I have created a simple Custom Post Type which has a few textboxes and one checkbox. Textbox values are getting saved and updated perfectly in `wp_postmeta` table but I am not being able to save the Checkbox value.

Below is my code:

```
function clients_custom_metaboxes() {
    // StreetAddress
    add_meta_box(
        'clients_street',
        __( 'Street Address' ),
        'infotravel_clients_street_metabox',
        'clients'
    );

    ...

    //Visibility
    add_meta_box(
        'clients_visible',
        __( 'Show on clients page' ),
        'infotravel_clients_visible_metabox',
        'clients'
    );
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'clients_custom_metaboxes' );

function infotravel_clients_street_metabox( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'clients_street', 'clients_street_nonce' );
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_clients_street', true );
    ?>
    <input class="trek_inputs required" value="<?php echo $value ?>" type="text" id="txtClientsStreet" name="txtClientsStreet" maxlength="200" required placeholder="Street address" />
    <?php
}

function infotravel_clients_visible_metabox( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'clients_show', 'clients_show_nonce' );
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_clients_show', true );
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkClientShow" name="chkClientShow" value="<?php echo $value ?>" />
    <label for="chkClientShow">Show this client on Clients page</label>
    <?php
}


function infotravel_save_clients_meta( $post_id ) {
    if(
        ! isset( $_POST['clients_street_nonce'] ) ||
        ! isset( $_POST['clients_show_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id) ) {
        return;
    }

    // mandatory fields
    $street_address = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['txtClientsStreet']  );
    $visible        = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['chkClientShow'] );

    $short_address  = $street_address . ', ' . $city . ', ' . $state;
    $full_address   = $short_address . ', ' . $zip . ', ' . $country;

    /**
     * Update meta information
     */

    update_post_meta( $post_id,  '_clients_street', $street_address );
    update_post_meta( $post_id,  '_clients_show', $visible );
    update_post_meta( $post_id,  '_clients_short_address', $short_address );
    update_post_meta( $post_id,  '_clients_full_address', $full_address );
}

add_action( 'save_post',  'infotravel_save_clients_meta' );
```

What I am missing?

DATABASE SCREENSHOT

[image]

**Further Testing**

I added a value (`xxxxxxx`) in `_clients_show` field and checked what I am getting when `metabox` is created:

```
function infotravel_clients_visible_metabox( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'clients_show', 'clients_show_nonce' );
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_clients_show', true );
    print_r($value);
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkClientShow" name="chkClientShow" checked="checked" />
    <label for="chkClientShow">Show this client on Clients page</label>
    <?php
}
```

Surprisngly, the value is not displaying!!

Comment: Have you tried logging the `$_POST` output? You are trying to run `sanitize_text_field()` on the checkbox value, which may be causing the problem. Try just outputting its value first. A checkbox is a boolean, so you shouldn't need to sanitize it at all.

Comment: Actually I tried without sanitization and it didn't work. I also tried to print the value by `echo`-ing `$_POST['chkClientShow']` inside the function hooked to `save_post` action but nothing got displayed. Maybe I am trying to print it at a wrong place?

Comment: Right, you can't echo anything in that hook because it's never actually displaying on the screen. Instead you could `fopen()` and `fwrite()` the variable to a temporary text log to see what prints out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the problem is the way you operate the checkbox.
As the checkbox value, you set the value read from the database, which is sometimes an empty string.

When you send an unchecked checkbox, there is no `$_POST['chkClientShow']` key and an empty string is saved to the database.
Then the empty string is set as the checkbox value. From now, the custom field `_clients_show` always will be an empty string.

The following code should work

```
function infotravel_clients_visible_metabox( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'clients_show', 'clients_show_nonce' );
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_clients_show', true );
    $is_checked = ($value == 1) ? 'checked' : '';
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkClientShow" name="chkClientShow" value="1" <?php echo $is_checked; ?>/>
    <label for="chkClientShow">Show this client on Clients page</label>
    <?php
}
```

```
function infotravel_save_clients_meta( $post_id ) 
{
    //
    // ...
    //

    $visible = isset( $_POST['chkClientShow'] ) && $_POST['chkClientShow'] == 1;
    $visible = (int)$visible;
    update_post_meta( $post_id,  '_clients_show', $visible );

    //
    // ...
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I however, had to change `$is_checked = ($value == 1) ? 'checked' : '';` to `$is_checked = ((int)$value == 1) ? 'checked' : '';`